# Updates report page shows "No Available Releases Found" in red for core and most modules even though the site is on 9.3.3

Tags: upgrading

See screenshots. Upgraded a site from D8 to D9 and the updates status page is mostly red warnings with "No available releases found" errors. I've cleared caches. Not sure what's going on here.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Update module has failed to reach drupal.org to get the update data.  If the site can make outgoing network connections, try uninstalling and then reinstalling the core Update module.

Comment: Re-installed core update status module did not fix the issue.

Comment: Did you move to a new platform or hosting provider around the time you upgraded? I *think* update module errors are logged in this case, which may shed some light on this. Yes, most likely the update module cannot make a network connection to the updates feed. This question has been asked many times.

Comment: No, on the same platform. I did make a dev copy on a different Linux server but the issue is on both my dev server and the prod server (Linode and A2 Hosting). Such a perplexing issue. I've worked on over 100 Drupal sites from D6 through D9 and have never seen this issue.